# ASP.NET MVC: posting a certain object to the controller)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, models

When I create a form to send data about new message:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>                            

    <%= Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message.Text) %>

    <input type="submit" />

<% } %>
```

I can't receive the message class in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewMessage(Message message) // will not work, message is null
```

Instead I have to use the model class that's passed to the view and then get the child class from it

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewMessage(NewMessageModel model) {
    Message message = model.Message;
```

And only after that I can do validation stuff.

Is there a way to pass a certain object to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult NewMessage([Bind(Prefix="Message")]Message message)
```